# Problema com "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" em recursão

Tags: java

Estou tentando implementar uma árvore genealógica em Java mas acabei me deparando com esse problema que não sei resolver:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at Arvore.antecessores(Arvore.java:11)
>    at Arvore.antecessores(Arvore.java:12)
>    at Arvore.antecessores(Arvore.java:12)
>    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
> ```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arvore genealofica = new Arvore();
        Pessoa joao = new Pessoa("Joao", null, null);
        Pessoa maria = new Pessoa("Maria", null, null);
        Pessoa adele = new Pessoa("Adele", maria, joao);
        Pessoa barney = new Pessoa("Barney", null, adele);

        genealofica.adicionar(joao);
        genealofica.adicionar(maria);
        genealofica.adicionar(adele);
        genealofica.adicionar(barney);

        genealofica.antecessores(barney);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arvore {
    ArrayList<Pessoa> arvoreGenealogica = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

    public void adicionar(Pessoa qualquer){
        arvoreGenealogica.add(qualquer);
    }

    public void antecessores(Pessoa a){
        if(!a.getPai().equals(null)){
            antecessores(a.getPai());
        }
        if(!a.getMae().equals(null)){
            antecessores(a.getMae());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(a.getNome());
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////

public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private Pessoa mae;
    private Pessoa pai;

    public Pessoa(String nome, Pessoa mae, Pessoa pai){
        setMae(mae);
        setPai(pai);
        setNome(nome);
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }


    public void setMae(Pessoa mae) {
        this.mae = mae;
    }

    public Pessoa getMae() {
        return mae;
    }

    public void setPai(Pessoa pai) {
        this.pai = pai;
    }

    public Pessoa getPai() {
        return pai;
    }
}
```

Comment: Felipe, a resposta do Renan Araujo me parece boa, só fica atento nas exclamações de acordo com o teste que precisa...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro acontece ao realizar a operação null.equals(null) ao tentar obter o pai de Barney.

Você deve usar operador == para verificar a *referência* e não o valor.

```
public void antecessores(Pessoa a){
    if(a.getPai() != null){
        antecessores(a.getPai());
    }
    if(a.getMae() != null){
        antecessores(a.getMae());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(a.getNome());
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBatista Obrigado pela observação Luis, alterei a resposta.

Comment: Boa sacada! Estamos ai!!! Abraço.

Comment: Opa, Renan! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Concertei o meu código de acordo com a sua recomendação e agora ela ta funcionando normalmente.